# What is the interface type format in the angular cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I was looking at the docs and became lost.

`ng generate interface <name> <type>`

However it doesn't tell what to put in for type. Like is it just a string, object, array, etc or can I specify properties like `email:String username:String age:Number`?

Comment: You can see the blueprint files: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/%40angular/cli/blueprints/interface

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ng generate   will generate

filename `<name>.<type>.ts`
content:

```
export interface <name> { //camel case

}
```

ie

`ng generate interface Itest sometype`
generates
file name `itest.sometype.ts`
content

```
export interface Itest {
}
```

Comment: Using Angular 5.1 I seem to have to specify type with `-t` flag. Details can be seen by running: `ng g i --help`

Answer (score 3):

Using Angular `CLI`,

```
ng g i filename
```

will create a file by the name `filename.ts` and
will have export interface `filename {}` in it

Answer (score 1):

Like so :

```
interface GraphDatas {
  firstTemperature: Period
  internalTemperature: {
    min: number;
    max: number;
  };
  secondTemperature: Period;
  thresholdAlerts: Threshold;
}

interface Period {
  currentPeriod: number;
  previousPeriod: any;  // TO DO
}

interface Threshold extends Period {
  hasBeenRead: number;
}
```

You will need to export the interface you want to use in your typescript file after that :

```
export interface test{
  listComputedDatas: GraphDatas;
}
```

And in your code :

```
import {test} from './pathToInterface';

...

randomProperty: test;
// Typescript should detect properties such as 
// randomProperty.listComputedDatas.internalTemperature.min
```

EDIT : You will be faster creating your own file manually than doing the `angular-cli` command...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

```
ng generate interface fruit
```

generates

```
fruit.ts
```

which contains the interface

```
export interface fruit {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must be using the new Angular Console that for some reason requires a "type" even though it is only a developer option. I would simply use "data", or "method", or "multi" if it contains both data structure and methods. I don't think it refers to the data type property (number, boolean, etc.). IMO it shouldn't be required in Angular Console. In your case I would probably use "data", giving it a capital I name by convention, and if you later need an interface for a method, create a separate interface. Also watch which directory it goes into when using Angular Console. Eg. I want an interface for cars data - in Angular Console it would be Name "Icars", data type "data", and thus creates icars.data.ts and with this content `export interface Icars {}`.

From Angular docs at: https://angular.io/cli/generate

> ng generate interface   [options] ng g interface 
>    [options] Creates a new generic interface definition in the
>   given or default project.
>
> Arguments ARGUMENT    DESCRIPTION    The name of the interface.
>
> Adds a developer-defined type to the filename, in the format
>   "name.type.ts".